# Copy files with Remote App on Windows 10

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-10-pro

I am using the Remote Desktop App on Windows 10 pro. Not the old program, the app. This is another issue but secondary to this. I will say though that everything on both sides is fully up to date, I can connect from the old program from machines running 10 Home but I get unsolvable authentication issues from Pro.

I was at one time able to copy files using the App from local to remote. I have seen questions indicating this wasn't possible at one time. But it was possible I have done it. It does require some permissions to be set though.

Starting Thursday I am unable to copy files though. When I try and paste the files on the remote server it tells me I need to configure permissions. However on my local machine under settings privacy and file system under "Choose Which apps can access your file system" Remote Desktop is in there. And on. Only office and it are listed. I toggled it off and back on to be sure but nothing.

I am kind of feeling this is some sort of broken windows update that means I can no longer do this, but maybe I am missing something. All my searching leads to non relevant information about the old RDC application or that this never worked in the app. Kind of stuck and looking for ideas.